# Gradlew unable to find a javac compiler

Tags: java, eclipse

So I am trying to create a Workspace for eclipse from gradlew. And I am getting the following error:

```
Execution failed for task ':makeStart'.
> Unable to find a javac compiler;
com.sun.tools.javac.Main is not on the classpath.
Perhaps JAVA_HOME does not point to the JDK.
It is currently set to "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_131"
```

But I`ve set JRE_HOME and JAVA_HOME correctly(JAVA_HOME points to jdk folder and JRE_HOME to jre folder). But gradlew sees wrong jdk path. What may caurse this problem?

Comment: Also I`ve echo both pathes in cmd and both are correct. Maybe a restart may solve a problem?

Answer (score 2):

> It is currently set to "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_131"

That means you do **not** have a JDK installed, but a JRE, meaning, you only have the runtime environment but not the development kit that contains the compiler.

Install a Java JDK and set the environment accordingly.

Comment: There is a JDK installed. It is shown in CP and it is on the last version.

Comment: Then your `JAVA_HOME` is wrong. It points to a JRE, according to the error you have shown.

Comment: C:\Program Files\Java\ **jre** 1.8.0_131. You have a _bin_ subdirectory with `javac` in that directory?